# How to remove or edit 'Value Data Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project'?

Tags: pycharm, regedit

When you right-click (in general) inside any folder, one of the options is 'Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project'. Actually, it helps a lot. But it just does not look good.
The size of that whole option menu is not good fit for the other option.

I want to edit 'Value Data Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project' ?
to any short sentence/option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple :
When you right-click (in general) inside any folder, one of the options is 'Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project'. Actually, it helps a lot. But it just does not look good.

You can find the solution for deleting it. I want that functionality but I want to just rename that option. See the option 'Open with Code', it looks very good.
So, you can rename it to whatever you want.
(Recommendation: Rename it to "Open with PyCharm").

1. Open 'Registry Editor' ( --->Press Win + R --->type regedit--->click 'ok' ---> click 'yes')
2. Navigate to the Location: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PyCharm Community Edition
   --->Click on that folder which is left side, "PyCharm Community Edition"
   --->Double Click on (Default), and a Window will pop up "Edit String"
   By default looks like this :
   Value Name :(Default)
   Value Data: Open Folder as Pycharm Community Edition Project
3. You can change the value data to whatever you want
   My Recommendation is Rename it to "Open with PyCharm"
   After, it should look like this:
   Value Data: Open with PyCharm
4. Follow the same procedure for the Location
   Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PyCharm Community Edition

If you want to remove that option, follow the same procedure.
And instead of renaming it, just delete that folder.

You can apply this to other software/application option also.